# How can I create this animation on select?

Tags: flutter, dart

I need to make an animation, but I don't know how to do it. When the user clicks on one of the avatars, the avatar will have a blue outline and the camera icon will appear on the selected avatar, the text accompanies the blue color when the avatar is selected. Can you help me please :___.

This is the code:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const SettingUser(),
    );
  }
}

class SettingUser extends StatefulWidget {
  const SettingUser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SettingUser> createState() => _SettingUserState();
}

class _SettingUserState extends State<SettingUser> {
  bool saved = false;
  ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? imageSelect;

  Future<bool?> showConfirmationDialog() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text(
              'Exit App',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            content: const Text(
                'Exit app'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                child: const Text('CANCELAR'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text(
                    'EXIT',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  )),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  imageGallery() async {
    final XFile? imageTemp = await imagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );

    setState(() {
      imageSelect = imageTemp;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildUserAvatar({
    required ImageProvider image,
    required String name,
  }) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        imageGallery();
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 10.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 5.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              child: CircleAvatar(
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF3E0A6),
                radius: 30.0,
                backgroundImage: image, // if image is a Image
                child: Align(
                  alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                  child: CircleAvatar(
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    radius: 12.0,
                    child: Icon(
                      Icons.camera_alt,
                      size: 12.0,
                      color: Colors.white,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                name,
                style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _renderUserAvatar() {
    if (imageSelect != null) {
      return _buildUserAvatar(
        name: 'Avatar 1',
        image: FileImage(File(imageSelect!.path)),
      );
    }

    return _buildUserAvatar(
      name: 'Avatar 1',
      image: AssetImage('assets/images/euQ.png'),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (!saved) {
          final confirmation = await showConfirmationDialog();
          return confirmation ?? false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: Icon(Icons.help_outline,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                'Select Avatar:',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff8194A9),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                _renderUserAvatar(),
                _buildUserAvatar(
                  name: 'Avatar 2',
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/'),
                ),
                _buildUserAvatar(
                  name: 'Avatar 3',
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/'),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            // ButtonConfig(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 10.0, right: 180.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showConfirmationDialog();
                },
                child: Text(
                  'Exit App',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  //elevation: 1,
                  primary: Colors.white,
                  padding:
                  EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                  textStyle: TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  side: BorderSide(
                    width: 1.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make it work only on the first avatar.

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: const SettingUser(),
    );
  }
}

class SettingUser extends StatefulWidget {
  const SettingUser({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SettingUser> createState() => _SettingUserState();
}

class _SettingUserState extends State<SettingUser> {
  bool saved = false;
  ImagePicker imagePicker = ImagePicker();
  XFile? imageSelect;

  Future<bool?> showConfirmationDialog() {
    return showDialog(
        context: context,
        builder: (context) {
          return AlertDialog(
            title: const Text(
              'Exit App',
              style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            content: const Text(
                'Exit app'),
            actions: [
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context, false),
                child: const Text('CANCELAR'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                  onPressed: () {},
                  child: const Text(
                    'EXIT',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
                  )),
            ],
          );
        });
  }

  imageGallery() async {
    final XFile? imageTemp = await imagePicker.pickImage(
      source: ImageSource.gallery,
    );

    setState(() {
      imageSelect = imageTemp;
    });
  }

  Widget _buildUserAvatar(bool hasFocus, {
    required ImageProvider image,
    required String name,
  }) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        imageGallery();
      },
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 10.0, right: 0.0, bottom: 5.0),
        child: Column(
          children: [
            SizedBox(
              child: AnimatedContainer(
                duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 1000),
                width: hasFocus ? 120 : 100,
                height: hasFocus ? 120 : 100,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                  border: Border.all(
                    width: hasFocus ? 4 : 3,
                    color: hasFocus ? Colors.black : Colors.blue,
                  ),
                ),
                child: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: Color(0xFFF3E0A6),
                  radius: 30.0,
                  backgroundImage: image, // if image is a Image
                  child: Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: CircleAvatar(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                      radius: 12.0,
                      child: Icon(
                        Icons.camera_alt,
                        size: 12.0,
                        color: Colors.white,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
              child: Text(
                name,
                style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget _renderUserAvatar(bool hasFocus) {
    if (imageSelect != null) {
      return _buildUserAvatar(
        true,
        name: "Avatar 1",
        image: FileImage(File(imageSelect!.path)),
      );
    }

    return _buildUserAvatar(
      false,
      name: 'Avatar 1',
      image: AssetImage('assets/images/euQ.png'),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return WillPopScope(
      onWillPop: () async {
        if (!saved) {
          final confirmation = await showConfirmationDialog();
          return confirmation ?? false;
        }
        return true;
      },
      child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          elevation: 0,
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.blue),
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.help_outline,
              ),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        body: ListView(
          children: [
            const Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 5.0),
              child: Text(
                'Select Avatar:',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Color(0xff8194A9),
                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  fontSize: 14,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                _renderUserAvatar(true),
                _buildUserAvatar(
                  false,
                  name: 'Avatar 2',
                  image: AssetImage('assets/images/euQ.png'),
                ),
                 _buildUserAvatar(
                   false,
                   name: 'Avatar 3',
                   image: AssetImage('assets/images/euQ.png'),
                 ),
              ],
            ),
            // ButtonConfig(),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 15.0, top: 10.0, right: 180.0),
              child: ElevatedButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  showConfirmationDialog();
                },
                child: const Text(
                  'Exit App',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blue),
                ),
                style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                  //elevation: 1,
                  primary: Colors.white,
                  padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 10.0, vertical: 10.0),
                  textStyle: const TextStyle(
                    fontSize: 16,
                    fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                  ),
                  side: const BorderSide(
                    width: 1.0,
                    color: Colors.grey,
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```